# Using ko.applyBindingsToNode

Tags: knockout.js

In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8279akmL/11/, I am trying to bind the 'test' element to a variable called `currentPlace`which is an observable in my ViewModel. I am using the following knockout statement:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("test"),{text: currentPlace().name});
```

However, the `div` gets bound to the list item `locations[0]` - the item to which `currentPlace` is pointing to at the time of binding - instead of `currentPlace` itself.

When I update `currentPlace` to point to a different list item `locations[1]`, the `div` is not updated.

The `div` only updates when i change the value of `locations[0]`, in the example, I change it to 'FOOBAR'.

How can I bind the 'div' to `currentPlace` instead of `locations[0]`.

Comment: Just do not make `this.currentPlace` observable to prevent updating if you don't need it to be updated. `this.currentPlace = this.locations()[1];` should be enough.

Comment: Could you elaborate what the _question_ is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for Knockout to be able to update the binding, it needs to know which observables to watch. In your code, you're just passing the `name` observable to the binding. It doesn't know about the `currentPlace` observable since it was unwrapped before calling `ko.applyBindingsToNode`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var theObservable = currentPlace().name;
ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("test"), {text: theObservable});
```

There are two options to fix this: 1) create a pureComputed that returns the correct name, or 2) use `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` to pass the entire logic of getting the name to Knockout. Here is your example updated to use the latter approach:

```
ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(
    document.getElementById("test"), 
    { text: function() {return currentPlace().name} });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8279akmL/12/